# Unable to create database when running flask app

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm new to flask and I got stuck into one thing. So I have `run.py` file inside it

```
from market import app
from market.models import db

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()

        app.run(debug=True)
```

so when I call `python run.py` the `db.create_all()` function works. But when I call `flask --app market run` or `flask --app run.py run` the `db.create_all()` doesn't get executed.

Please explain why this happens ?

Comment: and if you put `db.create_all()` before the app_context, what happen ? you delete the databases between calls ?

Comment: I didn't understand what you said?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run **python run.py**, then the value of `__name__` inside your run.py is `__main__`. That's why `if __name__ == "__main__"` condition satisfies and `db.create_all()` executed.

When you don't execute your main script directly but with flask cli, the value of the `__name__` in run.py file is equal to your file name. So your if condition is false and `db.create_all()` is not executed.

In addition, `__name__` is a special built-in variable in python that provides the name of the current module. Check this answer to learn more about it [What does if __name__ == "__main__": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

Comment: Make sense now.

Answer (score 2):

I have figured out the answer. Do export `FLASK_APP=run.py` , then running `flask --app run.py run` runs perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

`flask --app run.py run` does not execute the contents of your ifmain block, including the `db.create_all()`.

You can/should move the `with app.app_context(): db.create_all()` out of the ifmain.